# Loading data of XML into Oracle table

Tags: xml, oracle

So I have an XML file like

```
<TRNX_DATA transactionSeq="2">
  <TRNX_DATAITEMS sequence="0" name="INDIVIDUAL" value="POS"/>
  <TRNX_DATAITEMS sequence="1" name="FAMILY" value="130"/>
  <TRNX_DATAITEMS sequence="2" name="FAMILY_DATA" value="160"/>
</TRNX_DATA>
```

and want to load this in Oracle table(id, name, value) so my oracle table would look like

```
ID  NAME         VALUE
----------------------
0   INDIVIDUAL    POS
1   FAMILY        130
2   FAMILY_DATA   160
```

Any suggestions best approach for doing so?